# Which role playing games are suitable for a family with children under 10?

Tags: game-recommendation, kids

First post; please be gentle.  I grew up in an environment with no exposure to role playing games (only child, frequent relocation, no base of friends).

Now I have three children of my own.  I want to give them a broad experience of games and game playing beyond the computer or board game variety.  They are 4, 6 and 8; all three are creative and imaginative.

Which role playing games are suitable for families, or should I wait a few more years?

Comment: Hi Venture2099, unfortunately we don't handle game recommendation requests here anymore. You can instead ask about this on a forum ([such as one of these we've gathered a list of](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449)) or join us in [chat] to talk with us about it as well.

Comment: Also, you might like to check the content of the [tag:kids] tag on here.

Comment: K - no worries.  Thanks @doppelgreener; I will jump into chat.